# Почему вызов плагина jquery-validate происходит со второго раза?

Tags: javascript, jquery, валидация

Пытаюсь сделать валидацию формы с помощью плагина [jquery-validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/):

```js
// Callback forms
(function(){

  var app = { 

    init: function(){
      this.setUpListeners();
    },

    setUpListeners: function(){

      $(document).on('submit', 'form', this.submitForm);
      $(document).on('keyup', 'input', this.removeError);
    },

    submitForm: function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

      var form = $(this),
          btnSubmit = form.find('[type="submit"]');

      if(app.validateForm(form) === false) return false;


      btnSubmit.addClass('disabled');

      var str = form.serialize();

      $.ajax({
        url: 'contacts.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: str
      }).done(function(msg){

        if(msg === "OK"){
          var res = "<div class=\"alert alert-success\" role=\"alert\"> <strong>Well done!</strong> You successfully read this important alert message. </div>";
          $(".fancybox").html(res);

          setTimeout(function(){
            $.fancybox.close();
          }, 2000)

          console.log('ok');

          $(".fancybox").fancybox().trigger('click');
        }else {
          $(".fancybox").html(msg);

          $(".fancybox").fancybox().trigger('click');
        }                    

      }).always(function(){
        btnSubmit.removeAttr('disabled', '');                    
      });
    },

    validateForm: function(form){
      var inputs = form.find('input'),
          valid = true;
      
      
      form.validate({
        invalidHandler: function(event, validator){
          var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
          if (errors) {
            valid = false;
          } else {
            console.log('valide');
          }
          
          validator.focusInvalid();
        }
      });

      return valid;
    },

    removeError: function(){
      var $this = $(this),
          formGroup = $this.closest('.form-group');

      formGroup.removeClass('has-danger');
    }
  }

  app.init();
})();

 if($(".modalbox").length){
   $(".modalbox").fancybox({
     fitToView   : false,
     autoSize    : false,
     closeClick  : false,
     maxWidth    : 502,
     maxHeight   : 444,
     prevEffect  : 'none',
     nextEffect  : 'none',
     padding     : 0,
     margin      : 50,
     closeBtn  : false,
     helpers : {
       overlay : {
         css : {
           'background' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.72)'
         }
       },
     }
   }); 
 }
```

```css
.callback-modal {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.1/additional-methods.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrap">
  <a href="#request" class="modalbox">Оформить заявку</a>
  
  <div id="request" class="callback-modal">
    <div class="callback-modal__inner">
      <form class="callback__form" id="callbackForm">

        <div class="form-row">                            
          <input type="text" name="name" id="r-name" placeholder="Имя" class="input" data-rule-required="true">                            
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">                            
          <input type="text" name="phone" id="r-phone" placeholder="Телефон" class="input" data-rule-required="true" data-rule-minlength="5">                            
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">                            
          <input type="text" name="email" id="r-email" placeholder="E-mail" class="input" data-rule-required="true" data-rule-email="true">                            
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">                            
          <textarea name="msg" id="r-msg" placeholder="Описание сайта" class="input"></textarea>                            
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Отправить" class="btn btn__submit">

        <div class="fancybox"></div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

Но не могу понять, почему срабатывает проверка, только со второго раза? Возможно кто-то работал с данным плагином.

Как можно исправить модуль, чтобы плагин срабатывал и срабатывал как положено (если поля не заполнены, форма не отправляется отображаются error поля, если все в порядке, то отправляются данные)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае происходит неверное использование плагина. Перед тем как использовать что-то, это что-то надо инициализировать.

По аналогии, рассчитывать, что сработает *this.submitForm* при отправке формы, не вызвав *app.init*.

---

Далее, сама инициализация, выполнена не совсем корректна.

В документации к плагину можно увидеть, что [свойство invalidHandler](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#invalidhandler) нужно для выполнения *своего кода* в случае если валидация не прошла. В коде в вопросе, в этом методе идет выставление переменной *valid*, которая в коде используется для *определения* того, прошла валидация или нет.

Вместо это нужно было использовать [метод *form*](https://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.form/), который как раз возвращает результат проверки, без дополнительных переменных.

В итоге метод *validateForm: function(form){* можно удалить и заменить его использование на одну строку

```
form.validate().form()
```

В этом случае плагин **не** будет инициализирован дважды и более раз, ввиду наличия проверки внутри самого плагина.

Пример:

```js
// Callback forms
(function() {

  var app = {

    init: function() {
      this.setUpListeners();
    },

    setUpListeners: function() {

      $(document).on('submit', 'form', this.submitForm);
      $(document).on('keyup', 'input', this.removeError);
    },
    submitForm: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var form = $(this),
        btnSubmit = form.find('[type="submit"]');

      if (form.validate().form() === false) return false;


      btnSubmit.addClass('disabled');

      var str = form.serialize();

      $.ajax({
        url: 'contacts.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: str
      }).done(function(msg) {

        if (msg === "OK") {
          var res = "<div class=\"alert alert-success\" role=\"alert\"> <strong>Well done!</strong> You successfully read this important alert message. </div>";
          $(".fancybox").html(res);

          setTimeout(function() {
            $.fancybox.close();
          }, 2000)

          console.log('ok');

          $(".fancybox").fancybox().trigger('click');
        } else {
          $(".fancybox").html(msg);

          $(".fancybox").fancybox().trigger('click');
        }

      }).always(function() {
        btnSubmit.removeAttr('disabled', '');
      });
    },

    removeError: function() {
      var $this = $(this),
        formGroup = $this.closest('.form-group');

      formGroup.removeClass('has-danger');
    }
  }

  app.init();
})();

if ($(".modalbox").length) {
  $(".modalbox").fancybox({
    fitToView: false,
    autoSize: false,
    closeClick: false,
    maxWidth: 502,
    maxHeight: 444,
    prevEffect: 'none',
    nextEffect: 'none',
    padding: 0,
    margin: 50,
    closeBtn: false,
    helpers: {
      overlay: {
        css: {
          'background': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.72)'
        }
      },
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.callback-modal {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.1/additional-methods.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <a href="#request" class="modalbox">Оформить заявку</a>

  <div id="request" class="callback-modal">
    <div class="callback-modal__inner">
      <form class="callback__form" id="callbackForm">

        <div class="form-row">
          <input type="text" name="name" id="r-name" placeholder="Имя" class="input" data-rule-required="true">
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
          <input type="text" name="phone" id="r-phone" placeholder="Телефон" class="input" data-rule-required="true" data-rule-minlength="5">
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
          <input type="text" name="email" id="r-email" placeholder="E-mail" class="input" data-rule-required="true" data-rule-email="true">
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
          <textarea name="msg" id="r-msg" placeholder="Описание сайта" class="input"></textarea>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Отправить" class="btn btn__submit">

        <div class="fancybox"></div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Это супер ответ!!!! СПАСИБО!!!!)

Answer (score 1):

Как я понял - нужно перед началом работы с валидацией проинициализировать validate для формы. Т.е. вызвать `$("form").validate()` после загрузки DOM и скриптов. В вашем примере я просто написал это перед app.init() (97 строка js) и форма начала работать с 1ого раза.

Comment: тогда смысл модуля теряется, а хотелось бы именно с помощью модуля реализовать. но спасибо, если ничего уже не получится, то придется так делать (((

Comment: Я тоже сначала удивился - ведь модульно сделано=) Но судя по реакции на первый вызов validate() - он начисто игнорирует все ендпоинты, что могут быть описаны внутри (типа OnError, onSuccess  и т.п.). Я пытался получить ответ на первый вызов validate - у меня не удалось. Можно сделать инициализацию валидации по вызову как пример (чтобы каждый раз оно не вызвалось в начале работы приложения, а только непосредственно перед началом работы с валидацией). А потом уже использовать ваш validate с опциями.

Comment: @Elena Semenchenko как же теряется. Смысл валидации на JS - динамически выдавать подсказки, подсвечивать зелёным/красным. А больше нету смысла в ней. Т.к. есть JS валидация или нет - валидация должна быть и с серверной стороны. А проверять по сабмиту на JS - зачем два раза валидировать, если  можно отправить серверу, провалидировать там, и вернуть ошибки.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр, смысл вместе с модулем использовать и именно  в такой структуре! Вопрос почему инициализация происходит со второго раза!

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko ну со второго раза т.к. только по нажатию кнопки происходит вызов validate вообще. Поэтому (как я описал выше) первый проход запускает инциализацию вообще, а только второй валидирует. Прошу прощения если это очевидный факт - просто хотел прояснить этот момент. А что если поместить .validate в точку `init: function()` ? будет вызываться сразу при инциалзации модуля. Но есть минус - каждый последующий вызов init будет вызывать срабатываение validate